# More intuitive way of using a variable as a default value for a TCL procedure

Tags: variables, arguments, tcl, dereference, procedures

So, I used the thread of a similar name to get this working using the list command. Here is my working code:

```
proc E364xA::Connect [list [list VisaAlias ${E364xA::DefaultAlias}]] {

    ::VISA::Connect $VisaAlias
}
```

Now this is working currently by using the value stored in DefaultAlias within the namespace eval. I was wondering if there is a more intuitive way of doing this like:

```
proc E364xA::Connect {{VisaAlias ${E364xA::DefaultAlias}}} {

    ::VISA::Connect $VisaAlias
}
```

This way you wouldn't have two list commands muddling the waters. Any Ideas?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Some clarifications were made to my answer. You can keep @HaiVu's accepted answer--I agree that that is a clearer way of doing things--but if it's concision you want, then mine might help.

Comment: Do you want the content of the variable at the time the procedure is _created_ or at the time the procedure is _called_? In Tcl, this is a very important distinction.

Comment: @acheong87 I've accepted your answer since it was closer to answering the question I asked. I do believe HaiVu's is probably the best way to solve the issue overall, but it will evaluate the variable at the time it is called. I need this value to be set at time of creation since it refers to a value that is hard coded into devices of a certain series. I also wanted the line to be visually similar to {{VisaAlias "E364xA"}} my consciense just wouldn't let me hardcode the value.

Comment: @donal I believe my last comment answers your question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this? (Removed previous edits.)

```
proc E364xA::Connect "{VisaAlias {$E364xA::DefaultAlias}}" {

    ::VISA::Connect $VisaAlias
}
```

**Test**

Here's a simplified test:

```
set def "hello, world!"

proc test "{var {$def}}" {
    puts $var
}

test
```

Outputting:

```
hello, world!
```

Comment: @HaiVu - Thanks, fixed. Temporarily lost the Internet.

Comment: No, the variable name is `{VisaAlias` (with an open brace). The argument list is a list, so it does not add clarity to make it a string that gets transformed into a list.

Comment: @glennjackman - Hm. I'm afraid I don't understand. Could you clarify? I edited my answer to include a test case. Maybe I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. `info args test` and `info default test var value` show you are correct.

Comment: Ah, this is perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. I tested it and it works flawlessly. Thanks! +1

Comment: @glennjackman - Ah, I forgot about `info`--would've been much more useful if I showed that.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see any different way which offers more syntactic sugar. However, you can do something like:

```
proc E364xA::Connect {{VisaAlias -use-default}} {
    if {$VisaAlias == "-use-default"} { 
        set VisaAlias ${E364xA::DefaultAlias}
    }

    ::VISA::Connect $VisaAlias
}
```

Example Usage:

```
E364xA::Connect                 ;# Use the default value
E364xA::Connect -use-default    ;# Use the default value
E364xA::Connect somethingElse   ;# Non default
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I think this gives the best idea of what the code is doing to someone looking over it. Doesn't look like TCL has the functionality I was wanting to use, but I believe this accomplishes the same goal.

Comment: Actually acheong87 posted a very nice answer that I have accepted that uses double quotes to solve this problem. Take a look at it.

Comment: For Tcl 8.5 and above, use `eq` for string comparison: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/expr.htm#M14

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `args` argument, but it's not much clearer than your code, and it hides the fact that your proc should take at most 1 argument.

```
proc E364xA::Connect args {
    if {[llength $args] == 0} {
        set VisaAlias $E364xA::DefaultAlias
    } else {
        set VisaAlias [lindex $args 0]
    }
    ::VISA::Connect $VisaAlias
}
```

or

```
proc E364xA::Connect args {
    ::VISA::Connect [expr {[llength $args] ? [lindex $args 0] : $E364xA::DefaultAlias}]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought thought to use args since I'm pretty new to TCL. However, I do agree with you on it not helping clarity very much. I tried a few ways with args and it just didn't look too nice. Thanks for the idea though! +1

Comment: Thank you, Glenn. At work, we are still at Tcl 8.4 without any plan to upgrade to 8.5. I did not know about eq until now.